# How does snowflake takes a descision whether the file being loaded is a new one or its duplicate

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to perform copy into action from stage in Snowflake and snowflake logic seems to be broken when performing copy into action. It loads the same file again and again.

```
>put file:///Users/rsrivastava/Desktop/axion_customer_details_16062023.csv @test_stage AUTO_COMPRESS=FALSE SOURCE_COMPRESSION=NONE;

+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------+

| source | target | source_size | target_size | source_compression | target_compression | status | message |

|-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------|

| axion_customer_details_16062023.csv | axion_customer_details_16062023.csv | 311688 | 31208 | NONE | NONE | UPLOADED | |

+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------+

1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 4.741s

>ls @test_stage;

+-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+

| name | size | md5 | last_modified |

|-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------+------------------------------|

| axion_customer_details_16062023.csv | 31208 | 46d67085ed8de1984257a91f4a18be6 | Fri, 16 Jun 2023 10:02:36 GMT |

+-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+

1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.136s

> copy into employee_axion_frontend_tb from @test_stage/axion_customer_details_16062023.csv;

file status rows_parsed rows_loaded error_limit 

test_stage/axion_customer_details_16062023.csv LOADED 1024 1024 1 0
```

Now, I remove the file

```
>rm @test_stage/axion_customer_details_16062023.csv;

+-----------------------------+---------+

| name | result |

|-----------------------------+---------|

| test_stage/axion_customer_details_16062023.csv  | removed |

+-----------------------------+---------+

1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.441s

>put file:///Users/rsrivastava/Desktop/axion_customer_details_16062023.csv  @test_stage AUTO_COMPRESS=FALSE SOURCE_COMPRESSION=NONE;

+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------+

| source | target | source_size | target_size | source_compression | target_compression | status | message |

|-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------|

| axion_customer_details_16062023.csv  | axion_customer_details_16062023.csv  | 311688 | 31208 | NONE | NONE | UPLOADED | |

+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------+
```

Running the list again to see validate file got uploaded.

```
>ls @test_stage;

+-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+

| name | size | md5 | last_modified |

|-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------+------------------------------|

| axion_customer_details_16062023.csv | 31208 | 63c78086xu6rt4795551b45f4v18cy7 | Fri, 16 Jun 2023 10:14:06 GMT |

+-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Copy into again on the same file and snowflake loads it.

```
> copy into employee_axion_frontend_tb from @test_stage/axion_customer_details_16062023.csv;
```

I reviewed this article posted but it does not works for me.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Duplicate-files-getting-loaded-in-Snowflake-from-external-AWS-buckets-OR-Azure-containers

My expectation is snowflake should not load the duplicate file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Snowflake internal stage for performing copy into action whereas in the kb link, the stages used are external stage. When using PUT to ingest the files in Snowflake internal stage, the default encryption used is client side encryption. So every time the file is ingested, a random key is used to encrypt it. Thus at every upload, you see a different MD5/ETAG value of the file. Since the file is being uploaded by a random key every time, the ETAG value changes at each load and Snowflake thinks it is a new file and needs to be loaded when performing copy into.

AS for your case, re-create the stage with the below encryption type and re-perform the steps. This will by pass the default encryption to Server Side encryption.

> ENCRYPTION = (TYPE='SNOWFLAKE_SSE')